# Maximum call stack size exceeded (modal)?

Tags: angularjs

Im getting this error when i try to call modal on click.

I have this route in angular:

```
.state('language.modal', {
            url: '/modal',
            templateUrl:
                function (stateParams) {
                    return mainTemplateService.getTemplateUrl(stateParams, '/ticket/index');
                }
        });
```

This is how i call modal on click:

```
 $modal.open({
       templateUrl: '/modal',
       controller: 'sportOfferModalController',
       resolve: {
       items: function() {
           return $scope.TicketDetail;
          }
        }
  });
```

Any suggestion how can i fix this error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$stateParams`? Show code for template service

Comment: @charlietfl i cant display anything from modal...i always get maximum call stack size exceeded even when i have just <h3></h3> inside template

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl i tried but without success because i have routes and stuff..do u have any suggestion what  i need to check ?

Comment: From the error message, seems you have a non-stop recursive calling of some function somewhere.